# How to create two columns without blocking horizontal rows

Tags: javascript, html, css, rows

I have got a Wordpress loop of posts. This outputs some kind of post-list. To make it easy, we can consider it a `ordered-list` like that:

```
<ol>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ol>
```

Each list item got a unique, different height. When a certain device width is given, I want them to display side by side, without a "row like behavior". So each column should place the next post right below it, like illustrated below (no unnecessary white space below the shorter items):

[image]

Using `float`, `flex-box` and `css-grid` or `display: inline-block` did not work for me.

Although I would love to avoid two loops with the same content inside my DOM, as its a bad behavior for screen-readers etc.

Is there a solution I do not see without a lot of javascript? The internet is full of `float: left;` examples searching for "two columns", "flexible columns" and I did not find anything helpful.

Comment: check masonary https://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: You should look into using a grid framework. So much easier. But, for vanilla CSS, you'll need to set up a media query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `display: flex` and **`flex-direction: column;`**. By adding a **height** (or max-height) to the parent container, you make the elements automatically go to next column. Then you can change `order` attribute of some element to push them into the second row.

*This solution is not very generic as it will depend on the content, but it may give an idea on how you can do it.*

```js
$('li').each(function() {
  $(this).css('height',Math.floor((Math.random() * 50) + 30)+"px");
})
```

```css
ol {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 100vh;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align:center;
  padding: 10px;
  background: red;
  max-width: 50%;
  margin: 5px;
}
li:nth-child(2n) {
  background:green;
  order:1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ol>
```

**Important notice** (added by @Marian Rick):

- This approach does only work if the left column is bigger than the right one
- You need to set a fixed height, which does not allow dynamic content

Both of these problems can be solved using a javascript snippet to keep the solution dynamic.

Comment: thanks a lot @TemaniAfif, I always thought inside the `flex-direction: row` container, instead of `column` :)

Comment: @Zvezdas1989 not sure why, but in your solution you have some white spaces, maybe its not needed

Comment: @TemaniAfif we should include a javascript for a basic height calculation, so that the answer fits all of the questions needs. I am working on this solution for my own and will provide it when its finished.

Comment: @MarianRick, yes you can add JS for height calculation, this won't affect what i have done, it will always behave as it's now ... You simply need to adjust the different values (max-height, padding, order, etc) and also add media query if needed

Comment: @MarianRick i added a function to randomly calculate height, you can check the result ;)

Comment: @MarianRick i am not ok with the notices you wanted to add to my solution. It's not true that this solution works only with fixed height. You can set up max-height, % height, etc and the `li` element doesn't need fixed height too (i only use height to make them different

Comment: The idea behind the concept is to display two rows, but from left to the right and than top to bottom. This follows a logical order easy to achieve. Next we want to kill not wanted white space between each row. Your solution does work, but only, if the height (it does not matter if its `px,%, vh` and/or `max-width/width` matches the height of the left column (odd list items). Otherwise, the *second most important child* will be placed below all the other `odd` childs (which may be on the bottom of the page). because of that its limited and I think its a important notice.

Comment: @MarianRick i totaly agree and that's why i said it's no a generic solution ... it's strictly depend on the content, i simply highlighted the idea as i have no idea of the content and the page. The main idea with this solution is the use of **column** and order. Then to achieve something exact we of course need to do more stuffs :)

Comment: Yes, and its a great approach I am thankfully using. But I think, the "important notices" are important to state out, so that others can have a better understanding of what this solution can provide and what it cannot provide. Its not about saying "thats wrong", but about improving the quality of stack.

Comment: @MarianRick i added them back so ;) i also added your name so that we know that you have done tests and find this issues :)

Answer (score 1):

I have another fancy answer. It uses flex-direction:coulmn and the page-break-before to force every second elemend in the second column. This way you have no restriction to the height of the full list.
Please check the jsfiddle in a separate tab to check how I used the breakpoint to toggle from normal listing to two coulmns.

Also check if it runs in all targeted browser: https://caniuse.com/#search=page-break-before

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
article {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border:1px solid grey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  section {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  article {
    width: 50%;
  }
   article:nth-child(even) {
     order: 2;
   }
   article:nth-child(2) {
     /* this breaks into the second column after the 2nd child
     (which is not the first element of the second half of elements) */
     page-break-before: always;
   }
}

/* just for demo */  
article:first-child {
  height: 66px;
  background-color: #e0e0fe;
}
article:nth-child(4) {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #aee0e0;
}
article:nth-child(6) {
  height: 130px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article>1</article>
  <article>2</article>
  <article>3</article>
  <article>4</article>
  <article>5</article>
  <article>6</article>
  <article>7</article>
</section>
```

Comment: we don't see the breaking

Comment: @Fabian this indeed is a fancy approach. As Caniuse states out, the partial support should only affect `avoid` and the prefix. While using an autoprefixer and not using `avoid` I still get a wrong result in every browser. Can you check or confirm this? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XzqLoM

Comment: No. I am sorry. I trusted caniuse too much. It only works properly in FF for me.

Comment: Same here. Thanks a lot for this approach. Besides browser-support its the best and cleanest answer so far :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [great idea of @TemaniAfif](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47457187/2113599), I have written a small, barely tested jQuery snippet, that achieves the following:

- Each item will be placed as close as possible to the top, regarding to its position inside the container
- While resizing the browser, each item updates its position
- Its very few and fast javascript, while CSS does most of the work

The whole concept is still based on the idea of pushing items either to the left or right side, using the `order: x` attribute.

There is a **[CODEPEN DEMO](https://codepen.io/marianrick/pen/POeMVN)** to play around with.

**Notice:** Browser support is equal to the browser support of flex-box.

```js
"use strict";

// DEMO STYLE - Should be removed
// calculate random heights for each item
$("li").each(function() {
  $(this).css("height", Math.floor(Math.random() * 300 + 2) + "px");
});


///////////////////////
// Calculate columns
//
// 1. loop through each item.
// 2. first get the height of item
// 3. than check which column is shorter
// 4. if left column is shorter or equal, keep item on the left side
// 5. if right column is shorter, push this item to the right side
// 6. check which side will be higher
// 7. if left column is higher, assign height of column to parent container
// 8. if right column is higher, create a margin-bottom equal of the column offset and assign it to the left column
// calculation is finished. test it.

// finally add the height of the bigger column to the div
// if its the left column, assign the height of the right
var container = $("ol");
var items = container.find("li");
var breakPoint = 768; // if equal or bigger, the calculation will be fired

var calcPositions = function calcPositions() {

  // quit function if its a mobile device
  if ($(window).width() < breakPoint) return;

  // reset margin of left column item
  container.find("li.push-left").last().css("margin-bottom", "15px");

  var leftColumnHeight = 0;
  var rightColumnHeight = 0;

  // 1. loop through each item
  items.each(function(i, e) {
  
    // 2. get height of item
    var height = $(this).outerHeight(true);

    // 3. check which column is shorter
    if (leftColumnHeight <= rightColumnHeight) {
    
      // 4. if left column is shorter or equal, keep item on the left side
      leftColumnHeight += height;
      $(this).removeClass("push-right").addClass("push-left");
      return; // skip rest and continue with next item
    }

    // 5. if right column is shorter, push this item to the right side
    // using .push-right { order: 5 } inside css
    rightColumnHeight += height;
    $(this).removeClass("push-left").addClass("push-right");
  });

  // 6. check which side will be higher
  if (leftColumnHeight >= rightColumnHeight) {
  
    // 7. if left column is higher, assign height of column to parent container
    container.height(leftColumnHeight);
    return; // end of function
  }

  // 8. if right column is higher, create a margin-bottom equal of the column offset and assign it to the left column
  // otherwhise the second object can be displayed at the bottom of the left column

  // get offset of columns
  var columnOffset = rightColumnHeight - leftColumnHeight;

  // assign offset to last element of left sidebar
  container.find("li.push-left").last().css("margin-bottom", columnOffset + "px");

  // assign height to container
  container.height(rightColumnHeight);
};

// calculate initially
calcPositions();

// calculate on resize
$(window).resize(function() {
  calcPositions();
});
```

```css
/* functional classes needed for this grid */


/* keep this breakpoint in sync with "breakPoint" inside the javascript */

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  ol {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  
  li {
    max-width: 50%;
  }
  
  li.push-right {
    order: 1;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}


/* demo styles that can be removed */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ol {
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 800px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

li {
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  li {
    max-width: 49%;
    margin-right: 2%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Breakpoint is set to >=768px for two columns:</p>

<ol>
  <li>Lorem.</li>
  <li>Asperiores!</li>
  <li>Illum!</li>
  <li>Perspiciatis!</li>
  <li>Eius.</li>
  <li>Est.</li>
  <li>Quisquam.</li>
  <li>Eaque!</li>
  <li>Vero?</li>
  <li>Iste?</li>
  <li>Provident?</li>
  <li>Ipsum.</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: greate one ;) by the way you can remove prefixes on Snippet here to make the code lightweight ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `inline-block` if you want you avoid flex for some reason. Just use media queries when you to have all items in one column.

```css
div {
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
}

li {
  background: red;
  width: 49%;
  min-height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  li {
    width: 98%;
  }
}

.one {
  background: blue;
}

.three {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ol>
    <li class='one'>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li class='three'>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
  </ol>  
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion :) but as you can see, your examples does not work, as its divided into rows, instead floating each item beneath each other (no white space in each column)

Comment: @MarianRick It put items beneath each other when width of screen is smaller then 600px, I thought that's what you wanted to have two columns on desktop and one on mobile ?

Comment: @Zvezdas1989 yes but we shouldn't have the white gaps :)

Comment: @Zvezdas1989 its not about creating the columns, there are multiple easy ways to do it. Its more about creating a "fluid grid", which avoids to display unnecessary white-space. So each column ignores the divs of the other side. Its hard to explain, as I do not know the exact English words for it. I hope you get an idea of what I mean by checking the correct answer and look for visual differences :) thanks for your time anyways, I appreciate this.

Comment: @MarianRick Ah okay you can still use this code if needed `inline-blocks` create white space by default but that can be fixed easily.

Comment: @Zvezdas1989 and as far I know css, its not possible to achieve this by `display: inline-block;`. Because of that `display: flex; flex-direction: column` is the correct approach.